# Bind VMware to specific GPU

Tags: graphics-card, vmware-player

I have two GPUs in my setup and want to use GPU A for games while GPU B handles VMware VMs.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I don't think VMs use the physical graphics cards as they are purely software based.

Comment: @Burgi I'm sure OP did not mean PCI passthrough

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible if you have two Nvidia graphics card.

- Open *Nvidia Control Panel* and navigate to *Manage 3D Settings*<sup>1</sup> → *Program Settings.*<sup>2</sup>

[image: 1st screenshot]

- Select your program<sup>3</sup> or if not found add it to your list.<sup>4</sup>

[image: 2nd screenshot]

- Now you can specificate the GPU used for *CUDA*<sup>5</sup> and *OpenGL Rendering*.<sup>6</sup> select your preferred GPU<sup>7</sup> and you're good to go.

[image: 3rd screenshot]